# Operator ==, Equal Method and Object.ReferenceEqual in C#

Tags: c#, .net, equality, equals-operator, referenceequals

Today, I was reading about == operator, Equal function, and Object.ReferenceEqual method.

- Operator == It is used for check equal references.
- Equal Method - It is used for check equal values.
- Object.ReferencEqual – It is used for check equal references.

I have created a test console application. I have few questions. It would be helpful for me if you give me all the answers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int intValue = 5;
        string strValue = "5";
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  ", intValue.ToString() == strValue));// Output is TRUE
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  ", intValue.Equals(strValue))); // Output is FALSE
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  ", intValue.ToString().Equals(strValue))); // Output is TRUE 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  ", object.ReferenceEquals(intValue, strValue)));// Output is FALSE
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  ", object.ReferenceEquals(intValue.ToString(), strValue)));// Output is FALSE


        Console.Read(); 
    }
```

I have five lines in the Output.

Line 1 – Output is True.

According to my knowledge, Here I am doing casting. So I am getting TRUE as == operator check references.

Line 2 – Output is False.

**Question 1. Equal function check value of the object. Here we have same value, but I am getting False. WHY?**

Line 3 – Output is True.

**Question 2. Here I am doing casting, so I am getting True. WHY?**

Line 4. Output is False.

According to my knowledge, both the objects are different type. So, I am getting FALSE.

Line 5. Output is False.

**Question 3. Here I am doing casting, but still I am getting False. WHY?**

**Question 4. What is difference between == Operator and Object.ReferenceEqual?**

Comment: operator == has been overloaded on strings and compare their values not their references.

Comment: Your question talks about casting, but there is absolutely no casting shown in your sample code.

Comment: Please, read the [Object.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation first. "The type of comparison between the current instance and the obj parameter depends on whether the current instance is a reference type or a value type.". So "It is used for check equal values" is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear your mind from these statements:

> Operator == It is used for check equal references.
>   Equal Method - It is used for check equal values.

Both `operator==` and `Equals` can be overridden to modify their behavior. Since `operator==` is not virtual it is known at compile time that which method is chosen but `Equals` is chosen at runtime base on object type. (The whole process of choosing appropriate method is called method resolution)

**Line 1: True**. Because `string.operator==` has chosen by compiler and it compares the strings not their references.

**Line 2: False**. Because `int.Equals(object)` is chosen by compiler and `object`(`strValue`) is a string not an `int`. `int` is not equal to `string` so it is false.

**Line 3: True**. Because `string.Equals(string)` is chosen by compiler and it checks equality of the values not references.

**Line 4: False**. Becuase `object.ReferenceEquals` checks for reference equality so the answer is obvious.

**Line 5: False**. Same as above. `intValue.ToString()` creates a new string object on memory with value of "5" and it is not the same object as `strValue` points to so the answer is false.

Answer (score 1):

> Equal function check value of the object. Here we have same value, but I am getting False. WHY?

Objects of different type cannot possibly have the same value. Your first object has an integer value of 5, while your second object has a string value `"5"`. String `"5"` is one of possible *representations* of the integer value 5 - namely, its decimal representation. However, it is not the same value. After all, you wouldn't expect `"101"` to be equal to 5, even though 101 is a binary representation of 5.

> Here I am doing casting, so I am getting True. WHY?

You are not doing casting, you are converting 5 to its decimal string representation, which is `"5"`.

> Here I am doing casting, but still I am getting False. WHY?

Because you get a different object with the same content (namely, a single character string with character `"5"` in it).

> What is difference between `==` Operator and `Object.ReferenceEqual`?

`Object.ReferenceEqual` ignores possible overloads of operator `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
It only returns true if the type is of Int32, but it's a string
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z(v=vs.110).aspx

Question 2:
string.Equals return true if the values are the same, which they are, in both cases: "5".
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx

Question 3:
They point to different objects, hence ReferenceEqual returns false
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx

Question 4:
== is the same as referenceequal, except for string. But == operator can be overloaded, so if you want to test identity, use ReferenceEquals
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/6a71f45d.aspx